# Is "optical illusion" a tautology?

Tags: meaning

An illusion is a "visual deception", so is there any type other than "optical"?

Comment: That is an interesting question on pseudoptics -I need to think this through...

Comment: Did you try searching illusion ?

Comment: I've written about this before but I am uncertain that you can separate the 'optical' out of any illusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusion) an illusion is any distortion of the senses. Dictionaries similarly don't explicitly define illusions as visual.

So no - it's not a tautology, *optical* defines what kind of illusion it is.

An example of an auditory illusion, is the [Sheppard's tone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfJa3IC1txI).

Answer (score 4):

Optical illusion is not a tautology, any more than an *auditory hallucination* is.

An [illusion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/illusion) is a thing that is or is likely to be wrongly perceived or interpreted by the senses. The word comes from the Latin for "to play against" or "to mock".

There are sensory illusions other than optical. There are auditory illusions, olfactory illusions, illusions of time (a boring lecture can last *forever*), illusions of space, etc. Anything that can be ***perceived*** can be ***deceived*** under the right circumstances.

Such an illusion can be experienced by running cold water over your forearm for a minute; then change it to warm water and place first your dry forearm under the warm water; you will perceive its temperature accurately. Placing the wet, cold forearm under the warm water will give you the sensory illusion that the water is almost *hot.*

Answer (score -3):

**Paramnesia** or **Reduplicative paramnesia** are both delusional beliefs but whereas paramnesia is a 'déjà vu' experience and thus optically induced, reduplicative paramnesia is a belief [that a place or location has been duplicated, existing in two or more places simultaneously, or that it has been 'relocated' to another site. It is one of the delusional misidentification syndromes and, although rare, is most commonly associated with acquired brain injury, particularly simultaneous damage to the right cerebral hemisphere and to both frontal lobes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplicative_paramnesia)

So, a neuropsychological illusion is brain induced first, and the optical memory of the familiar place was not factual but a brain reprinting of what is a new area...chicken and egg?